# How do I bulk upload photos with either Plogger or Zenphoto? Or are there alternative photo management CMSs that allow for bulk upload?

Tags: uploading, photo-gallery

I would like to use either the Plogger or Zenphoto CMS to implement a client's website of photo galleries. The client would like to upload around 1000 photos.

So far, I have found no bulk upload feature for Plogger or Zenphoto that meets my needs. Both CMSs offer just two ways to bulk upload photos:

1. Specify a folder on the server to upload.
2. Upload a zip file of photos.

Way 1 is not feasible since I'm not giving my client FTP access to my server. Way 2 is not feasible since .zip uploads are limited to 7MB by PHP.

Are there plugins out there or features I am not privy to that allow for bulk upload via an interface for the client?

By the way, I am also open to other photo CMSs that meet my needs for bulk upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress now has multiple uploads into it's media manager.

There are [quite a few options](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=automatic%20gallery) for auto-generated gallery plugins like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-content-gallery-plugin/) and you can implement the excellent timthumb script for automatic image optimization. Both of these solutions have worked well for me on several sites.

If you relent on an FTP based solution the [Grou Random Image Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/grou-random-image-widget/) can be easily extended.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer for gallery pages to be automatically generated though and the images' resolutions to be reduced for web viewing.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match your concerns.